# Extracting JSON properties using JSON Parser - Coin Market Cap API

Tags: json, vba, api, object, coinbase-api

I am using the JsonConverter.bas module to parse the json received from my call (see below)

```
{
  "status": {
    "timestamp": "2020-06-01T07:43:13.192Z",
    "error_code": 0,
    "error_message": null,
    "elapsed": 15,
    "credit_count": 1,
    "notice": null
  },
  "data": {
    "ETH": {
      "id": 1027,
      "name": "Ethereum",
      "symbol": "ETH",
      "slug": "ethereum",
      "num_market_pairs": 5250,
      "date_added": "2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z",
      "tags": ["mineable"],
      "max_supply": null,
      "circulating_supply": 111165464.9365,
      "total_supply": 111165464.9365,
      "is_active": 1,
      "platform": null,
      "cmc_rank": 2,
      "is_fiat": 0,
      "last_updated": "2020-06-01T07:41:24.000Z",
      "quote": {
        "GBP": {
          "price": 192.38035284151908,
          "volume_24h": 10939279331.24139,
          "percent_change_1h": -0.0312479,
          "percent_change_24h": 0.19816661,
          "percent_change_7d": 15.48893301,
          "market_cap": 21386051368.275387,
          "last_updated": "2020-06-01T07:41:01.000Z"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I attempt to get a property, let's say "id". I get a

> runtime error '424' - Object required.

I have tried:
initializing my JsonConverter instance as an Object/Variant/Dictionary
initializing my att iterative variable for looping as an Object/Variant/Dictionary.

In the code below both JSON and att variables are declared as Objects:

```
Sub TestApi()

Dim JSON As Object
Dim api_key As String
Dim explorer As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim endpoint As String

api_key = "********-****-****-****-************"
endpoint = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=ETH&convert=GBP"
Set explorer = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

explorer.Open "GET", endpoint, False
explorer.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
explorer.SetRequestHeader "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY", api_key
explorer.Send

Debug.Print explorer.responseText

Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(explorer.responseText)

Dim att As Object

For Each att In JSON("data")

  Debug.Print att("id")

Next att

End Sub
```

Ideally I'd like to pick a list of properties and have them printed or used in various functions.
Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: `Debug.Print JSON("data")(att)("id")`

Comment: I think you can't iterate JSON("data") because it is not a JSon array[]. See the first comment.

Comment: @omegastripes I've tried this solution in the loop and I still the object required error. I also tried to execute this line of code outside of the loop minus the (att) so: JSON("data")("id") - I get no error but I also get nothing printing in my immediate window. I'm getting the error on this line : For Each att In JSON. I'm going to try your suggestion with att as a Variant type.

Comment: @armagedescu Thanks for pointing this out. I worked with a JSON parser in the past that generate an array so I assumed this was the same..

Comment: Ok so I got it to print the id by removing the att variable and using an undeclared item variable in its place so:          `For Each item in JSON`. now I just have to figure out how get the price! Thanks for your help..

Comment: Just to add in case someone is trying to extract properties from a nested loop. Following on from the answer @omegastripes kindly gave above, it seems you need to 'drill' down to the group in which your property is contain. In my case it was the price I wanted which is nested in the "GBP" group. `JSON("data")(item)("quote")("GBP")("price")`